# Rijndael 128/256 decryption

Tags: java, encryption, aes, rijndael

I tried many answers from SO and all over the web but still without success.

I use following [tool](http://www.bierkandt.org/encryption/symmetric_encryption.php) to encrypt.

```
text to encrypt: tom
key: exo123exo1exo123
input (textfield or selected file above) is: text/binary
Convert output to: [i leave this unselected]
Mode: CTR
Ciphers: Rijndael-128 and Rijndael-256
```

After getting result I move [here](http://www.bierkandt.org/encryption/encoding.php):

and encode it with base64.

Then I copy string and send it as a parameter to my function:

```
public String authenticate(String base64EncodedData){

    byte[] input = Base64.decodeBase64(base64EncodedData);
    byte[] ivBytes = "1234567812345678".getBytes();


    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");

    cipher.init(
        Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,
        new SecretKeySpec("exo123exo1exo123".getBytes(), "AES"),
        new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes)
    );

    byte[] plainText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];
    int plainTextLength = cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, plainText, 0);
    plainTextLength += cipher.doFinal(plainText, plainTextLength);

    return new String(plainText);  
  }
```

Result I got is always something similar to this (no matter if I use Rijndael-128 or 256 encrypted string):

```
.�v�Y�
```

When I try to return `input` value - I get the encrypted string. So base64 works just fine. 
What I do wrong? 
Am slowly getting mad here. 
Thank you.

Comment: It seems that the way the site encrypts is non standard. There is no documentation how those parameters are used. I couldn't get a reproducible example. Why do you want to use this site?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I can use any other. Ultimately am just trying to encode Rijndael128 encrypted and base64 encoded string.
Have you tested this code on any other sites maybe?

Comment: I rolled back your last edit, because it doesn't actually help answer the question, because the first tool is so bad (see my answer). Also for the future, please don't respond to answers, by editing your question to say that the answer doesn't work. Update the code in a secret [gist](https://gist.github.com/) and only update really missing information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problem with your assumptions and your code:

1. The output of the first tool is already Base 64 encoded. RIJNDAEL-128: `r0GR` and RIJNDAEL-256: `yAVy`. It doesn't need to be encoded a second time. It automatically selects this option, because binary data cannot be printed.
2. There is no native Rijndael-256 in Java, you will have to use BouncyCastle for this. Rijndael-128 is supposed to be AES which means that both have a block size of 128-bit.
3. The IV almost certainly needs to consist of zero bytes. For example:

   ```
   byte[] ivBytes = new byte[16];
   Arrays.fill(ivBytes, (byte)0); // might not be necessary
   ```

   Note that CTR mode doesn't use an IV, but rather a nonce.
4. Always specify an encoding when retrieving bytes: `"exo123exo1exo123".getBytes("UTF-8")`. It is probably best to use UTF-8 everywhere. If you send data across systems that use different system encodings, it will lead to hard to find problems.

---

On second look at the online tool is not usable for anything, because it is unclear how it works. What I found:

- Any key produces a ciphertext regardless of size, which suggests that the "key" that you enter is actually *hashed* and there exist a million ways that could be done. I could decrypt it with the above method, so the key is actually uses as-is without hashing. This suggests that the key is filled up with 0x00 bytes until a valid key size. When the key size is too big, it is probably truncated.
- Plaintext of 16 characters encrypts to a ciphertext of 16 bytes (encoded 24) and a plaintext of 17 characters encrypts to a ciphertext of 32 bytes (encoded 44). This means that no discernible padding is used which might actually be zero padding.

And here is the **deal breaker**:

- Every time you encrypt something, you get a different ciphertext. In CBC mode it means a random IV is generated before encrypting. The problem is that this IV is not shown. So there is no way to decrypt this fully. So if you encrypt more than 16 characters you can recover all but the first 16 characters when you decrypt it in the way I describe it in the first part of this answer.

---

You shouldn't make your system dependent on closed source online tools. Write your own encryption tool. Some general advice:

- IV should be generated randomly every time you encrypt something. It is not secrect, but should be unique. Simply prepend it to the ciphertext after encryption and slice it off before decryption.
- Use an authenticated mode like CCM or GCM where possible. It is harder to do authenticated encryption yourself, but the other way to go would be to use encrypt-then-mac paradigm.

Comment: 1. Ok so I will not encode it again.
2. Than I ll use Rijndael-128
3. I can also use CBC (will try both)
4. I will specify the encoding

After doing that four steps will get back to you.
Thank you

Comment: Did what you adviced. Effect is in question, below the oryginal part of it. 
Any further advices?

Comment: I've looked at the tool closely. It is quite unusable. I cannot recommend any other online tool, but since you already have the decryption, writing the encryption easy. Note that you should actually use authenticated encryption. So I put some advice into my answer. Please read it carefully.

Comment: Great! Funny thing is I read more about AES, IVs and tried to test few online tools against each other and I got to just the same conclusions that you state under "here is the *deal breaker*". 
Also tried to encode longer than 16bit string and again - found what you write about, what got me to the place of "oh, ok so I need to know the IV also" thought:)
I found it astonishingly unreasonable that those tools are closed and not even trying to notify user about the consequences (what the should do as they are noobs tools by definition). 
Also thank you very much for editing my question.